# Is there a Windows or Angular variable that is populated when the user refreshes their screen?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I want to restore the state of the user data from localStorage when the user refreshes their screen. I tried the following:

```
this.products$.subscribe((productsState) => {
  this.products = productsState?.products;
  
  if(!this.products.length) {
    const userState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userState "));
    console.log('userState ', userState )
  }
});
```

But checking for the length of products is not viable because it is at times 0 even if the user doesn't refresh the screen. If there is a variable that is populated by Windows or Angular, I could use that to test if the user has refreshed the screen.

Comment: By "refreshed the screen" do you mean refreshed the browser tab? Because that's effectively identical to "loaded the app anew".

Comment: That's what I mean -- refresh the browser, load the app anew. If the user refreshes the screen intentionally or inadvertently, rather than a blank screen, I want to display what was previously on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs and how complex you want it to be, you can go by: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r6-detect-browser-refresh (from https://medium.com/front-end-tricks/detect-browser-refresh-with-angular-590cd21d2f02) or you can just use `ngAfterViewInit()` to trigger whatever you want when the page loads its content (which happens on reload too).

Comment: Jeez that's an old version of angular!

Comment: Heh true that, but NavigationStart is an option still.